# How to monitor network connectivity between the ports in different windows server?

Tags: networking, windows

I have a application hosted from one server which listens on to a specific port and listens to a service on a another server in a different port .

Seeing error log between XYZ application hosted on XX.XX.XX.XX and a service hosted on XX.XX.32.32
Now need to monitor network connectivity between this servers to see if there are any network drops.

Error says :
 An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://192.168.XX.XX:8888/sdf.svc

Comment: This question appears to be about windows services

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given much information to go on. You could try Wireshark or iptables (depending upon your configuration).

Comment: Ok , Seeing error log between XYZ application hosted on XX.XX.XX.XX and a service hosted on XX.XX.32.32
Now need to monitor network connectivity between this servers to see if there are any network drops.

Comment: What do you mean by "network drops"? Wireshark and iptables both allow you to see all the network traffic, but they are both low-level tools, which may make diagnostics problematic.